# undeleting uncommitted files in a directory

Tags: git

Some script erroneously deleted some files from a directory that I track with GIT. I have not committed these changes. When I run `git status` I see almost 100+ files deleted and it says `Changes not staged for commit` so I have not even done `git add` yet.

What is the best way to undelete all these files and get back to where I was. Note: I did not make any other changes to this repo. all changes I see by running `git status` are the files deleted erroneously.

Comment: Perform a rollback?

Comment: `use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory`

Comment: @JackManey I would have to run that command for each file. Is there a way to do that for all the deleted files

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "I did not make any other changes to this repo. all changes I see by running git status are the files deleted erroneously.", it is simply

```
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing, If you want to remove the local uncommited file changes then simply run

```
git checkout .   # Do to show you need to be in the project main directory otherwise command may fail
# Also you can mention the individual all file but then would be hectic in this case
```

But If you have committed some file locally and wanted to revert back them too then run this command multiple times till you cant see your local commit log using `git log`

```
git reset --hard HEAD^   # this will reset the git commit 1 step back
```

Then update the local repo

```
git pull origin <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case other changes were made so you don't want to `reset --hard` but all the files you want to undelete are in the same directory you can checkout the direcctory:

```
git checkout HEAD /path/to/files
```